# Creating a view like Newsstand using UICollectionview

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have used collection view to display my content `similar` as shown in below image . But I am not able to set the background image same as give in the image, as my cell is size of icons in it,I am not able to set backgroung image in to it as per row.

Is there any way I can set image in UICollectionView ?

[image]

**Edit :**

I will be using following image for all the rows of my colletion view.Above image is just the reference.

[image]
Any help appreciated .
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can:

1) You need a multi section collection view with supplementary views for each section.

2) You need to use a custom layout object to set the frame of the supplementary views to the whole section frame

3) And finally you need to set the background color of the supplementary to the desired color.

That way you will have a multicolor background for a collection view like the one you want to achieve

Comment: hey thanks for the info ,I would like to add one more thing,that my image will be same ,I just gave this image as reference .I will be having same image background for all the rows .So will there be any change in your steps ,please  ?

Comment: what does "your image" refer to?

Comment: I have updated my question with the image,I want to use as a background image.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand now. Then in step 3) you will need to do something like [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage"]]

Comment: Okay,one more thing in step 2,do you mean to add UICollectionViewFlowLayout ?
And , can you please add any sample code or reference link, to make it more live?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can subclass flowlayout, the important method you want to focus on is (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:(NSString *)supplementaryViewOfKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: Okay Thanks,let me try that :)

Answer (score 0):

set backgroundview.
    UIView *blueView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    blueView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    self.collectionView.backgroundView = blueView;